# Birkat hatorah before Zohar study

Tags: halacha, blessing, torah-study, zohar, orach-chaim

According to Halacha, does the Berakha of Birkat hatorah have to be recited before Zohar study? Is it similar to the Talmud or tanakh in this respect?

Comment: Assuming it's not heresy, and assuming you can understand it, it's probably most similar to agada.

Comment: You have to say birkhat HaTorah before both Talmud and Tanakh. What's the question?

Comment: @יהושעק The debate (Brachot 11b) is over four categories: Mikra Midrash Mishna Talmud. As I indicated above this is probably in Midrash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's Torah. There's no reason that Zohar shouldn't require a brachah.

Comment: If one disputes the authenticity of the zohar, which many of our greats did, then it is not Torah and it would most definitely not require a beracha beforehand, if anything it would be a beracha lvatala or worse

Comment: @Nahum What about if someone is not sure about the authenticity and is reading the Zohar for the purpose of investigating it?  I would think that investigation is still Talmud Torah even if the conclusion is that the Zohar itself is not.

Comment: Even if Moshe de Leon wrote the Zohar himself, would it not be his perush on Chumash and therefore Torah?

Comment: Heshy, perhaps comparable to a safek beracha which one does not make. Joshua K, I suppose his own legitimate commentary (if that exists) and the plagiarized stuff would be Torah, issue is all the potentially foreign/heretical/problematic statements that it contains. Maybe safek beracha. On the other hand the whole thing may be considered tainted.

Comment: "Many" is quite a strong word @Nahum

Comment: @RabbiKaii R Emden, R Sofer and R Fleckeles come to mind

Comment: @Nahum R Emden did not dispute the authenticity of the Zohar itself, just a few passages within it.

Comment: @RabbiKaii second column starting with ואני https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7920&st=&pgnum=43&hilite=

Comment: @Nahum are you saying based on what he wrote there, one shouldn't say birchat Hatorah before learning Zohar??

Comment: @RabbiKaii this site is not for halacha lmaaseh, see my comment above that starts with Heshy

Comment: @RabbiKaii To use an imperfect analogy Rambam holds that physics and metaphysics are the highest level of Torah while others would read it in the bathroom

Comment: @RabbiKaii I may have misunderstood your question. I was responding (with that link to m"u) to your assertion that there were only a few passages that aren't authentic; regarding problematic passages see mitpachat seforim where R Emden himself ids over 300 . .

Comment: @RabbiKaii A better analogy would be shiur komah which some consider the highest level of Torah and which Rambam wouldn't even read in the bathroom https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1730&st=&pgnum=216